# How to segregate days of weeks into 1 week each and perform functions on them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a stock market data like this

```
    Date           Open        High        Low        Close     Weekday

0   2007-09-17  4518.450195 4549.049805 4482.850098 4494.649902 Monday
1   2007-09-18  4494.100098 4551.799805 4481.549805 4546.200195 Tuesday
2   2007-09-19  4550.25     4739.0      4550.25     4732.350098 Wednesday
3   2007-09-20  4734.850098 4760.850098 4721.149902 4747.549805 Thursday
4   2007-09-21  4752.950195 4855.700195 4733.700195 4837.549805 Friday

5   2007-09-24  4837.149902 4941.149902 4837.149902 4932.200195 Monday
6   2007-09-25  4939.100098 4953.899902 4878.149902 4938.850098 Tuesday
7   2007-09-26  4937.600098 4980.850098 4930.350098 4940.5      Wednesday
8   2007-09-27  4942.700195 5016.399902 4942.700195 5000.549805 Thursday
9   2007-09-28  4996.450195 5055.799805 4996.450195 5021.350098 Friday

10  2007-10-01  5021.5      5089.299805 5001.350098 5068.950195 Monday
11  2007-10-03  5069.0      5261.350098 5034.149902 5210.799805 Wednesday
12  2007-10-04  5211.649902 5233.100098 5126.049805 5208.649902 Thursday
13  2007-10-05  5208.149902 5248.549805 5164.5      5185.850098 Friday
```

(I have put the gaps after friday for better visual representation)

I have converted the strings of dates into days of the week in `Weekday` column. What I want to do is for each week I want to find, which day had the lowest opening price and increment to that days variable. So here in the sample data it should be

Week 1 (index 0-4) - Tuesday has the lowest `Open` price

Week 2 (index 5-9) - Monday has the lowest `Open` price

Week 3 (index 10-13) - Monday has the lowest `Open` price

So it should print `Monday -2, Tuesday -1, Wednesday - 0, Thursday -0, Friday -0`

How can I do this?

Comment: `df.rolling('1W')` will give you windows of 1 week and it has `.min()` to get min value. From there it is a matter of formatting to get it the way you want

Comment: @noah I tried this and I got the error that the window must be an integer.

Comment: did you roll `on=Date`? Otherwise it will try to apply the datetime to the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to `groupby` every 5th obs -

```
df.groupby(df.index // 5)['Open'].min()

0    4494.100098
1    4837.149902
2    5021.500000
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

Get day of week with min Open Price per week -

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index // 5)['Open'].idxmin(),'Weekday']

1     Tuesday
5      Monday
10     Monday
Name: Weekday, dtype: object
```

Get the number of months -

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df.index // 5)['Open'].idxmin(),'Weekday'].value_counts()

Monday     2
Tuesday    1
Name: Weekday, dtype: int64
```

**Update**

For handling missing days, leverage the `Date` column to group -

```
df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.week)['Open'].idxmin(),'Weekday'].value_counts()

Monday     2
Tuesday    1
Name: Weekday, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but the only problem is that its not the 5th observation everytime, some weekdays the stockmarket is closed so that day is missing so then that messes up this calculation. How make the dataset uniform for your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the week number of the dates using the below code and then groupby to calculate the min opening price

```
df['week'] = df['date'].dt.week
df.groupby('week')['Open'].min()
```

after this you can get the respective day and then get the count of respective days.